# "Убедитесь, что расширение PHP mysqli установлено и включено."

Tags: php

Скачал с word press локальную копию сайта для работы с ним на своём ПК. Сайт на php. До этого с php не работал. Пытаюсь запустить код на vs code. Установил php server, php debug, php intelephense, и сам php в отдельную папку. Проблема в том, что при запуске проекта в режиме отладки получаю сообщение "Похоже, в вашей конфигурации PHP отсутствует расширение MySQL, необходимое для работы WordPress.
Убедитесь, что расширение PHP mysqli установлено и включено." Перечитал много разной инфы, покрутил настройки, но ошибка так и осталась. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, не знаю что делать. Мои настройки: в php.ini раскоментил extension=mysqli, extension=php_mysqli.dll. В самом vs code settings.json

```
""workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"php.validate.executablePath": "d:/php/php.exe",
"phpserver.phpPath": "d:/php/php.exe",
"php.debug.executablePath": "d:/php/php.exe"
```

" Команда phpinfo выдала информацию (на скриншоте).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что мешает вам воспользоваться Open Server Panel, например? Там ничего настраивать особо и не надо... https://ospanel.io/download/

Comment: Какая версия Wordpress? Просит именно MySQL (без i)? Расширение MySQL отсутствует в PHP версии 8.x по причине безопасности, но возможно очень старая версия WP еще работает с его помощью

Comment: lezhni: я не знаю какая версия WP. WP должен быть установлен на сервере где сам сайт, или на моём ПК?  Где посмотреть какая версия. Текст ошибки я скопировал в кавычках слово в слово. Версия php 8.2.6. Простите за глупые вопросы.

Comment: Alexey: это редактор, типа vs code?

Comment: Нет, это localhost-сервер для web-разработчиков с уже встроенным PHP, базами данных и множеством других плюшек...

Comment: Alexey:  спасибо, по пробую. Если что, напишу тогда